# loop is not working with secant method

Tags: c++, nested-loops

My program that i wrote to find the roots of an equation is nearly finished, but i have run in to a small problem. The nested loop i am using to assign the varying values of velocity and angle into the equations is not working. Somewhere either in the loop or in the call to the secant of fx there is a mistake that i am missing. It keeps giving me the same numbers for the root, number of iterations and f(x). If anyone could help me find my mistake i would greatly appreciate it :)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

// Declaration of functions used
void secant(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double&, int& );
double fx( double, double, double, double, double, double, double);

const double tol=0.0001;
// Tolerance for convergence
const int max_iter=50; // Maximum iterations allowed

// main program
int main()
{
    int iteration;  // Number of iterations    
    double kr, uc, q, b, radians; 
    double x0, x1;  // Starting values for x   
    double root;    // Root found by secant method
    const double PI = 4.0*atan(1.0);

    ifstream datain ("shuttle.txt");
    ofstream dataout ("results.txt");
    datain >> kr >> uc >> q >> b;

    int velocity = 16000;
    double angle =10;
    x0= 1000;
    x1 = 200;
    for (int velocity = 16000; velocity <= 17500; velocity += 500)
    {   
        for (int angle = 10; angle <= 70; angle += 15)
        { 
            radians= angle * PI/180  ; 
            cout << velocity << endl; 
            cout << radians << endl;   
            cout << angle << endl;                  
            secant (radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, x0, x1, root, iteration);      
        }
    } 
    system("pause");
}

// Definition of function "secant"
// Receives a, b, c, d and x0 values from main program
// Returns root and the iterations required
void secant(double radians,double velocity, double kr, double uc, double q, double b, double x0, double x1, double& root, int& iteration)
{    
    double xnminus1, xnplus1, xn; // Local variables
    iteration=0;    // Initialize iterations    
    xnminus1=x0;
    xn=x1;  
    do  
    {   
        ++iteration; 
        xnplus1 = xn - fx(radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, xn)*(xn-xnminus1)/(fx(radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, xn)-fx(radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, xnminus1)); 
        cout<<"x"<<iteration+1<<" = "<<xnplus1<<endl;  
        xnminus1 = xn;
        xn=xnplus1; 
    } while ((fabs(fx(radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, xnplus1)) >= tol )&& (iteration < max_iter)); 
    root=xnplus1;  
    cout<<"\nThe root is = "<<root<<endl; 
    cout<<"The number of iterations was = "<<iteration<<endl; 
    cout<<"The value of f(x) at the root = "<<fx(radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, root)<<endl<<endl;
}

// Defines "fx" 
double fx(double radians,double velocity, double kr, double uc, double q, double b, double ts)
{
    return kr * pow(ts,4.0) + uc * ts - q - pow(velocity / b, 2.0) * sin(radians);
}
```

Comment: Did you provide the proper input file `shuttle.txt` mentioned in the program?

Comment: I feel soooo stupid right now, i put it in the wrong directory, thanks dude, lol the dumb mistakes you make at 3 in the morning lol

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple defined variables, try removing the outer most velocity and angle in main:

```
int velocity = 16000; // remove this one
double angle =10; // and this one
x0= 1000;
x1 = 200;
for (int velocity = 16000; velocity <= 17500; velocity += 500)
{
        for (int angle = 10; angle <= 70; angle += 15)
        {
```